# Average value of distinct combinations

Tags: combinations, average

Distinct combinations of 123 are 123, 132, 213, 231, 312 & 321.
Adding those and dividing by 6 gives the average 222.

Same goes for 246: 246, 264, 426, 462, 624 & 642.
Added up and divided by 6 gives the average of 444.

However, if I take 235, the average is 370, so I "lost" my pattern. :-)

Is there a nice way to find the average of distinct combinations of a number?

Thanks,

Ole

Comment: so you would get $x=x_1x_2...x_n, x_i \in [0-9]$. Then you would have $n!$ ways to arrange the digits without repeats. So you would have to something like $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum x_i \cdot 10^n+...+\sum x_i \cdot 10^0}{n!}$, while taking into account the repeats (and whether or not a number like 22 would have 1 or 2 combinations for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average of $2,3,5$ is $3.333\dots$. So the average you are looking for is
a sum of this number in the hundreds, tens and units positions:

$333.333\dots + 33.333\dots + 3.333\dots = 370$

Comment: Thanks Marconius.
I've just tested this with 1234 as well.
Average of 1, 2, 3 & 4 is 2.5 + 25 + 250 + 2500 = 2777.5.
If I then need to total, I would multiply it with the factorial of the amount of digits (4) = 24 which comes out to 66660.

If I start complicating matters with repeating digits, I get the correct average, but the total becomes double:

1224.
Average digit is (1+2+2+4) / 9 = 2.25
2/25 + 22.5 + 225 + 2250 = 2499.75 which is the right average.
However, multiplying it with factorial of amount of digits (4) = 24 comes out to 59994, which is the double of the distinct total 29997.

Comment: The number of distinct permutations is given by the multinomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem. See the section "Number of unique permutations of words" near the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you arrange three distinct digits $a$, $b$ and $c$. Then the average is

$$\frac{(200+20+2)(a+b+c)}{6}=\frac{222(a+b+c)}{6}=37(a+b+c).$$

In general,

$$\frac{(n-1)!\left(10^{n-1}+10^{n-2}+...+10+1\right)(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)}{n!}\\=\frac{\left(10^n-1\right)(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)}{9n},$$

where $n \leq 9$ and $x_i\neq 0$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: Thanks James. While this works in your example (because a+b+c=6), I did not get this working in other examples.

Comment: $a+b+c$ need not be $6$. For exmaple, if we have $4$, $7$ and $9$, then the average $= \frac{479+497+749+794+947+974}{6}=740=\frac{999(20)}{27}.$ Indeed, the equation, having some limitations, cannot count the average of combinations with repeated digits and $0$.